# Oracle subquery: INTO clause is expected into this SELECT statement

Tags: oracle

Here is a simplified version of my function in a package

```
    function log_booking_mapping(
         pi_booking_id    in         VARCHAR2
        ,pi_event_id      in         VARCHAR2
        ...
        ,po_return        out        my_return_typ
    )
    return integer as
        ...
        v_event_id varchar2(200) := null;
    begin

        IF pi_event_id IS NULL OR TRIM(BOTH FROM pi_event_id) = '' THEN
            begin
                select EVENT_ID into v_event_id 
                    from (
                        select EVENT_ID, row_number() over (order by UPDATE_DATE desc) as seqnum
                            from BOOKING_MAPPING_LOG
                            WHERE BOOKING_ID = pi_booking_id
                    )
                    WHERE seqnum  = 1;
                IF v_event_id IS NULL THEN
                    return c_failure;
                END IF;
            exception
                when NO_DATA_FOUND then
                    return c_failure;
            end;
        ELSE
            v_event_id := pi_event_id;
        END IF;
        insert into BOOKING_MAPPING_LOG (
            ...
        ) values (
            ...
        );

        po_return := ...;
        return c_success;

    exception
        WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
            UPDATE BOOKING_MAPPING_LOG ...
                WHERE BOOKING_ID = pi_booking_id AND EVENT_ID = v_event_id;
        when OTHERS then
            ...
        return c_failure;
    end log_booking_mapping;
```

I am getting a warning about `seqnum` in the *subquery `SELECT`* :

```
INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

As a recap, here is the query (and its subquery) where I got the warning:

```
select EVENT_ID into v_event_id 
from (
    select EVENT_ID, row_number() over (order by UPDATE_DATE desc) as seqnum
    from BOOKING_MAPPING_LOG
    WHERE BOOKING_ID = pi_booking_id
)
WHERE seqnum  = 1;
```

I am not sure why this is, as I am trying to create two columns inside the subquery and pass them to the outer query to further select into variable.
I don't want to put the result of subquery in a variable for the outer query, so why should I use `INTO` for the subquery in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is piece of code you blame:

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_event_id varchar2(10);
  3  begin
  4    select 'x' into v_event_id
  5    from (select 'x' event_id,
  6                 row_number() over (order by null) seqnum
  7          from dual
  8         )
  9    where seqnum = 1;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

For me, it works OK, no error.

---

Though, you said that you are

> getting a **warning** about seqnum in the subquery SELECT :
>
> INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

What raises that warning? Is it Oracle itself (so you got ORA-xxxxx *error*), or is it a (GUI?) tool (if so, which one)?

Also, does it mean that you can successfully run your code, or does that "warning" prevents you from doing that?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL developer (Version 21). It it not an error. I can still compile. I just get a yellow underline warning from SQL Developer - I hover the underlined text and this warning pops up.

Comment: Ignore it, then. SQL Developer has wrongly identified a problem. It seems that it searches PL/SQL code for SELECT statement that doesn't contain an INTO clause.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have given, it will not raise an error about `INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`.

There are problems with your code:

- You do not define the `C_SuCCESS` or `C_FAILURE` variables in the code that you show us.
- `TRIM(BOTH FROM pi_event_id) = ''` will never be true as, in Oracle, `''` is the same as `NULL` and you would need to use `TRIM(BOTH FROM pi_event_id) IS NULL`.
- If `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` is raised then there is no `RETURN` statement and a run-time exception will be raised.

This code successfully compiles:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE function log_booking_mapping(
   pi_booking_id    in         VARCHAR2
  ,pi_event_id      in         VARCHAR2
  -- ...
  ,po_return        out        my_return_typ
)
return integer
as
  -- ...
  v_event_id varchar2(200) := null;
  c_failure  CONSTANT INTEGER := 0;
  c_success  CONSTANT INTEGER := 1;
begin
  IF TRIM(BOTH FROM pi_event_id) IS NULL THEN
    begin
      select EVENT_ID
      into   v_event_id 
      from (
        select EVENT_ID, row_number() over (order by UPDATE_DATE desc) as seqnum
        from BOOKING_MAPPING_LOG
        WHERE BOOKING_ID = pi_booking_id
      )
      WHERE seqnum  = 1;
      
      IF v_event_id IS NULL THEN
        return c_failure;
      END IF;
    exception
      when NO_DATA_FOUND then
        return c_failure;
    end;
  ELSE
    v_event_id := pi_event_id;
  END IF;

  insert into BOOKING_MAPPING_LOG (
    event_id,
    update_date,
    booking_id
  ) values (
    pi_event_id,
    SYSDATE,
    pi_booking_id
  );

  po_return := MY_RETURN_TYP('x', 'y');
  return c_success;
exception
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    UPDATE BOOKING_MAPPING_LOG
    SET update_date = SYSDATE
    WHERE BOOKING_ID = pi_booking_id AND EVENT_ID = v_event_id;

    RETURN c_success;
  when OTHERS then
    -- ...
    return c_failure;
end log_booking_mapping;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HCJjkjjf)

Comment: It is not an error. I can still compile. I just get a yellow underline warning from SQL Developer - I hover the underlined text and this warning pops up. Don't worried about c_success and c_failure - they are just predefined constants in the package. Thanks about the `TRIM` and `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` parts. I forgot about them.